# Prove $S=A-B$ is an open set where $A=(0,1),B=\{\frac{1}{2^n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> $S=A-B$ where, $A=(0,1),B=\{\frac{1}{2^n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
>   
> Prove that the set $S$ is an open set.

**My approach:**

$A$ is an open interval $\Rightarrow A$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Define $C:=B\cup\{0\}=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{2^n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

The derived set of $C, C'\subset C\Rightarrow C$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow C^c$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

Now, $0\notin A\Rightarrow A\cap\{0\}^c=A$

$\Rightarrow S=A-B=A\cap B^c=(A\cap B^c)\cap A=(A\cap B^c)\cap (A\cap\{0\}^c)=A\cap(B^c\cap\{0\}^c)$

$\Rightarrow S=A\cap(B\cup\{0\})^c=A\cap C^c$

$\because$ intersection of two open sets is open

$\therefore S$ is an open set.

> Is my approach correct?
>   
> Is there a more common approach to similar questions?

Comment: In the second line from bottom you meant intersection, not union, right? Otherwise you are fine.

Comment: @KaboMurphy I did, but I realized my method was flawed.  $C'\ne C$ but $C'\subseteq C$. The edit has been made, though.

Comment: There is no need to consider $C'$. Just verify that $A=A-C=A\cap C^{c}$ and observe that $C$ is closed.

Comment: @KaboMurphy the $A=A\cap C^c$ verification is necessary, got it. But, don't we need $C'$ to observe whether $C$ is closed/not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\setminus \overline B$ is open.

$\overline B = B \cup \{0\}$.

$A\setminus \overline B = (A\setminus B) \cap (A \setminus \{0\}) = (A\setminus B) \cap A = A\setminus B$.

Alternatively:

If $a \in S$, then there is $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} < a < \frac{1}{2^n}$. Then $(a-\delta,a+\delta) \subseteq S$ for $\delta = \frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$. Thus, every element of $S$ is contained in an open set totally contained in $S$, and s0 $S$ is open.